An infinite cyclic group has infinitely many irreducible real representations.
I'm trying to show that an infinite cyclic group $G=\langle g\rangle$ has infinitely many non-equivalent irreducible representations over $\mathbb{R}$. I have in mind the following argument, for which I'd like to have feedback or opinions since I'm not completely sure it is correct.
There is a natural bijection between irreducible real representations of $G$ and simple $\mathbb{R}[G]$-modules, with $\mathbb{R}[G]$ denoting the group algebra of $G$ over $\mathbb{R}$. So, the problem can be reduced to determining the number of non-isomorphic irreducible $\mathbb{R}[G]$-modules.
Now, any simple $\mathbb{R}[G]$-module $M$ is cyclic, so $M=\mathbb{R}[G]m$ for some $m\in M$ and by the fundamental isomorphism theorem we have that:
$$M\cong \mathbb{R}[G]/Ann_{\mathbb{R}[G]}(m).$$
Moreover, the natural assignment $g\mapsto x$ gives an isomorphism of $\mathbb{R}[G]=\mathbb{R}[g,g^{-1}]\cong\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$, with $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$ denoting the localization $S^{-1}\mathbb{R}[x]$ of the ring polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$ given by the set $S$ of the powers $x^i$, for $i\in\mathbb{N}$.
Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID. Hence, also $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$ is a PID, since, given any ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$, an immediate computation shows that there is an ideal $J$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ s.t. $I=JS^{-1}\mathbb{R}[x]$. So, if $p(x)$ is a generator of $J$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it is also a generator of $I$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$.
Since $M$ is simple, the image of the annihilator through the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}[G]\cong\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]$ is a maximal principal ideal $(p(x))$, with $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ irreducible polynomial. By maximality, the quotient $F=\mathbb{R}[x,x^{-1}]/(p(x))$ is a field, that can be seen as a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ induced by the minimal polynomial $p(x)$.
By a classic result in Galois Theory, the degree of the extension $F/\mathbb{R}$ is exactly the degree of $p(x)$. However, by the fundamental theorem of Algebra, every non-constant polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ can be reduced to a product of irreducible polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. Since $p(x)$ is assumed to be irreducible, it must have degree 1 or 2. So, in order to get the thesis it suffices to find infinitely many irreducible polynomials of degree 2 that are not scalar multiple of each other in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. To this extent we consider the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ associated to the polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$: for $f(x)$ to be irreducible, we must have $\Delta<0$, so we need to find a solution $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ of the following condition:
$$-\sqrt{4ac}<b<\sqrt{4ac}.$$
However, fixed some $b\in\mathbb{R}$, we can always find infinitely many $a,c\in\mathbb{R}$ realizing the above inequalities, and since $b$ is fixed, the resulting polynomials are not scalar multiple, as desired.

An easier way to do this is to observe that for any integer $n>2$ there is a irreducible $2$-dimensional representation with image a finite cyclic group of order $n$.

This is all fine but you are also working much too hard; you skipped the case of degree $1$ polynomials for some reason even though it is easier. $1$-dimensional representations correspond to homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ (on the nose; two such homomorphisms are equal iff the corresponding representations are isomorphic) and we can write all of them down, namely they are given by
$$\mathbb{Z} \ni n \mapsto r^n \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$$
for any $r \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. So there are uncountably many of them.
This is already enough to solve the problem as stated but we can keep going:

 The $2$-dimensional irreducible representations have the form $n \mapsto X^n$ where $X \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ does not have real eigenvalues, up to conjugacy. Your argument amounts to showing that $X$ can have infinitely many different characteristic polynomials, which is correct. But as Derek says we can exhibit an infinite set of these more directly and more geometrically: you can take $X$ to have order exactly $n \ge 3$ (e.g. a rotation of a regular $n$-gon) so that the image of the representation is cyclic of order $n$, and then the representations must be non-isomorphic because they have different images.

Passing to the group algebra and doing commutative algebra to it does work but at the cost of missing the very geometric flavor here: an isomorphism class of real representations of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a conjugacy class of invertible linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. We are talking about transformations of space here!

Thank you (and you too @Derek Holt)! Actually, your arguments are much better than mine :)
